# How to filter the intent according to his extra data?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, extras

I got some activity that have defined intent filter like this:

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>
```

But I want my activity to be shown in the list only if that intent contains i.putExtra("asd","asd"); 
so is there posibility to filter according the extras in the intent ?

Comment: If you have an intent filter named action.send , it will show in the list. Better handle the situation inside your app.